Eclipse PHPUnit 9 193 (%1 is not a valid Win32 app)
When running code coverage from Eclipse error 193 (%1 is not a valid Win32 app) occurs. When using the command line no problem.
How to solve this in Eclipse

Which operating system do you have and how have you configured PHP/PHPUnit 9 in the preferences?

Windows 11, what do you mean about PHPUnit 9 config?

Please improve your question instead adding comments to it. What do you have in Window > Preferences: PHP?
